# Program for trigrams

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program in python which is supposed to output the frequency of those trigrams from examens.txt that occur more than 3 times. The uppercase and lowercase of the words and special characters is to be ignored, and the output should be sorted by frequency.

My teacher told me that i have to change only two lines! But im getting python blind. For me the code looks correct, but it doesent work.

```
with open("examen.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    text = data.replace("\xad", "")

words = []
for word in data.lower().split():
    word = word.strip("‚‘!,.:«»-()'_#-–„“*?")
    if word != "":
        if not word[-1].isalnum():
            print(repr(word))
        words.append(word)

trigrams = {}
for i in range(len(words)):
    word = words[i]
    nextword = words[i + 1]
    nextnextword = words[i + 2]
    key = (word, nextword, nextnextword)
    trigrams[key] = trigrams.get(key, 0) + 1

l = list(trigrams.items())
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
l.reverse()
for key, count in trigrams:
    if count < 3:
        break
    word = key[0]
    nextword = key[1]
    nextnextword = key[2]
    print(word, nextword, nextnextword, count)
```

Comment: Have you tried executing it, do any errors show up?

Comment: What does the program output? How does this differ from your expectation?

Comment: A sample of your `examens.txt` would also be helpful and a much more detailed explanation of *does not work*. Does it crash? Does it produce wrong results?

Comment: As a first hint, [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) *returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed*. So all special chars inside words will stay. As an alternative, you could use [`str.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "‚‘!,.:«»-()'_#-–„“*?")`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

Comment: Also [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) can be used with the argument `reverse=True`.

Comment: There are actually 3 issues with your code. Revisit `range(len(words))` which results into an `IndexError`. Also look into iteration over dictionary keys/values and `break` vs. `continue`.

Answer (score 0):

You traverse too deep into `words` when you build the trigrams and you don't print the right data structure in the final loop.

Changing just two lines I would write -

```
with open("examen.txt") as f:
    data = f.read()
    text = data.replace("\xad", "")

words = []
for word in data.lower().split():
    word = word.strip("‚‘!,.:«»-()'_#-–„“*?")
    if word != "":
        if not word[-1].isalnum():
            print(repr(word))
        words.append(word)

trigrams = {}
for i in range(len(words) - 2):
    word = words[i]
    nextword = words[i + 1]
    nextnextword = words[i + 2]
    key = (word, nextword, nextnextword)
    trigrams[key] = trigrams.get(key, 0) + 1

l = list(trigrams.items())
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
l.reverse()
for key, count in l:
    if count < 3:
        continue
    word = key[0]
    nextword = key[1]
    nextnextword = key[2]
    print(word, nextword, nextnextword, count)
```